# Why is $_POST[''] not working with <form>

Tags: php, html

This is a Rock Paper Scissors game and I am just starting on it, but it will not display the `$_POST['keuzen']`.

So I don't get why this is not working. Tried many things but can't find a good solution.

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>RockPaperScissor</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="RockPaperScissor.php" method="post">
            <input type="image" src="steen.jpg" alt="steen" name="keuzen" value="steen" title="Steen">
            <input type="image" src="papier.jpg" alt="papier" name="keuzen" value="papier" title="Papier">
            <input type="image" src="schaar.jpg" alt="schaar" name="keuzen" value="schaar" title="Schaar">
        </form>
        <?php
            if (isset($_POST['keuzen'])) {
                $keuzen = $_POST['keuzen'];
                $kiezenuit = array("steen", "papier", "schaar");
                $random = rand(0, 2);
                $computer = $kiezenuit[$random];

                echo 'jij koos ' . $keuzen . '<br>';
                echo 'De computer koos ' . $computer . '<br';

                if ($keuzen == $computer) {
                    echo 'Resultaat : Draw ';
                }
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Replace `action="RockPaperScissor.php"` with simply `action=""`. Does it work?

Comment: Can you change name="keuzen" to name="keuzen[]"

Comment: Start simple debugging with `var_dump($_POST)`…

Comment: This did not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the form is in the same `RockPaperScissor.php` page, better introduce a hidden field that takes the value of a clicked image, but remove the `name` tag from the images itself:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>RockPaperScissor</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="RockPaperScissor.php" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="keuzen" value="">
            <input type="image" src="steen.jpg" alt="steen" value="steen" title="Steen" onclick="document.forms[0].keuzen.value=this.value">
            <input type="image" src="papier.jpg" alt="papier" value="papier" title="Papier" onclick="document.forms[0].keuzen.value=this.value">
            <input type="image" src="schaar.jpg" alt="schaar" value="schaar" title="Schaar" onclick="document.forms[0].keuzen.value=this.value">
        </form>
        <?php
            if (!empty($_POST['keuzen'])) {
                $keuzen = $_POST['keuzen'];
                $kiezenuit = array("steen", "papier", "schaar");
                $random = rand(0, 2);
                $computer = $kiezenuit[$random];

                echo 'jij koos ' . $keuzen . '<br>';
                echo 'De computer koos ' . $computer . '<br>';

                if ($keuzen == $computer) {
                    echo 'Resultaat : Draw ';
                }
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Upon `POST`, you will get the following:

```
Array
(
    [keuzen] => schaar
    [x] => 7
    [y] => 3
)

jij koos schaar
De computer koos schaar
Resultaat : Draw
```

Comment: Just a note. As @Quentin pointed below, `<input type="image">` is sending X/Y coordinates of the image itself upon POST, but not it's value. Bear in mind when playing with such type within a form.

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of `<input type="image" name="keuzen">` is to provide a server side **image map**. It submits the form as a side effect, but the purpose is to select coordinates on the image.

When you click it, x and y coordinates will be sent to the server.

If I remember correctly, you'll get something like `keuzen.y=123&keuzen.x=456` which PHP will use to populate `$_POST['keuzen_x']` and `$_POST['keuzen_y']` but **not** `$_POST['keuzen']`.

If you do a `var_dump($_POST)` you can see the data structure you actually get.

---

If you want to just have regular submit buttons which look like images, then use regular submit buttons containing images:

```
<button name="keuzen" value="steen"><img src="steen.jpg" alt="steen"></button>
```

You can style away the borders and background of the button element with CSS if you like.

Answer (score -2):

1. Change names of inputs like this: `name="keuzen[steen]"` and remove value attributes.
2. Read POSTed value like this: `$keuzen = array_keys($_POST['keuzen'])[0];`

You can also verify that the POSTed value is not empty.